# Displaying mySQL LEFT JOIN with multiple matches in second table correctly

Tags: mysql, select, left-join, inner-join

Here's our DB setup:

members:

[image: members table]

addresses:

[image: addresses table]

titles:

[image: titles table]

And this is the output we need:

> Mr John Doe Msc A-1100 Vienna (A00025)
>  
>   Mrs Jamie Smith A-4040 Linz (A00026)
>  
>   Jack Jones A-5020 Salzburg (A00027)

This is our mySQL statement so far:

```
SELECT T1.member_id, T1.surname, T1.firstname, T2.country, T2.zip, T2.town,
    T3.titel, T3.position FROM members T1 
    LEFT JOIN addresses T2
    ON T1.member_id = T2.member_id 
    LEFT JOIN titles T3
    ON T1.member_id = T3.member_id
    WHERE T2.type = "invoice"
```

This gives us:

> Mr John Doe A-1100 Vienna (A00025)
>   John Doe MSc A-1100 Vienna (A00025)
>   Mrs Jamie Smith A-4040 Linz (A00026)
>   Jack Jones A-5020 Salzburg (A00027)

How do we prevent John Doe from being listed twice?
How do we get both titles in the same line?

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is to join the titles table as many times as there can be different title positions so that you can access every different title/position from a different source.

If you want to produce a string like `Mr Doe John MSc A-1100 Vienna (A00025)` from your query you can use the `concat` function to build it.

```
SELECT 
  concat(
    case when t1.titel is null then '' else t1.titel end, 
    case when t1.titel is null then '' else ' ' end,
    m.firstname,  ' ',
    m.surname,  ' ',
    case when t2.titel is null then '' else t2.titel end,
    case when t2.titel is null then '' else ' ' end,
    a.country, '-', a.zip,  ' ',
    a.town, 
    ' (', m.member_id , ')'   
  ) AS LongString       

FROM members m 
JOIN addresses a
    ON m.member_id = a.member_id AND a.type = 'invoice'
LEFT JOIN titles t1
    ON m.member_id = t1.member_id AND t1.position = 'Before' 
LEFT JOIN titles t2
    ON m.member_id = t2.member_id AND t2.position = 'After'
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d715e/5)

Sample output:

```
|                             LONGSTRING |
|----------------------------------------|
| Mr John Doe MSc A-1100 Vienna (A00025) |
|   Mrs Jamie Smith A-4040 Linz (A00026) |
|    Jack Jones A-5020 Salzburg (A00027) |
```

Comment: Thanks jpw. Looks good. What if I don't know how many different title positions there are in the table?

Comment: @RichardTinkler If you don't know how many different titles there can be or what positions they should be in you need to use some kind of dynamic sql or maybe handle the query outside the database.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a maximum of only 1 title before and 1 title after:

```
SELECT T1.member_id, T1.surname, T1.firstname, 
    T2.country, T2.zip, T2.town,
    T3.titel AS titelBefore,
    T4.titel AS titelAfter,
FROM members T1 
   INNER JOIN addresses T2 ON (T1.member_id = T2.member_id) 
   LEFT JOIN titles T3 ON (T1.member_id = T3.member_id AND T3.position = "before")
   LEFT JOIN titles T4 ON (T1.member_id = T4.member_id AND T4.position = "after")
 WHERE T2.type = "invoice"
```

Please note the `INNER JOIN` for addresses, you don't need a `LEFT JOIN` since you state `T2.type = "invoice"` in your `WHERE`